# Google BigQuery GROUP BY ask for unwanted column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi I'm new to google bigquery and need help why my query isn't working? It keeps asking me to do a GROUP BY trip_end_timestamp which I don't want to do. Any idea?

```
SELECT 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM trip_end_timestamp) AS trip_year
, company
, SUM(trip_total) total_revenue  
FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM trip_end_timestamp) = 2015 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM trip_end_timestamp), company
HAVING total_revenue >= 30000000000
```

the error is

`SELECT list expression references column trip_end_timestamp which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:26]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: edited on my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery actually insists that you use the column alias in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM trip_end_timestamp) AS trip_year, company,
       SUM(trip_total) as total_revenue 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips` tt
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM trip_end_timestamp) = 2015 
GROUP BY trip_year, company
HAVING total_revenue >= 30000000000;
```

This is in contrast to the standard which does not require recognizing aliases in the `GROUP BY` -- and other databases where it is optional.

Comment: hi this helps. but one more thing, I can't use the column alias in the WHERE clause. So I can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, HAVING clause but not in WHERE clause?

Comment: Wow, so that's a seriously misleading error message, since it refers to the actual column name, not the alias.  Also, you use the calc in the where clause, not the alias?

Comment: @MohammadIqbal . . . You have that correct.  No aliases in the `WHERE` clause.